# Regexp, capture between parentheses, javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regexp that extracts values between parentheses.

It's working most of the time but not when it ends with a parentheses

```
var val = 'STR("ABC(t)")';
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;.
var matches = regExp.exec(val);
    ​
console.log(matches[1]); //"ABC(t"
```

What I want is `"ABC(t)".`

Any ideas how I can modify my regexp to Achive this?

**Update**
The value is always inside the parentheses.

Some examples:

```
'ASD("123")'; => '123'
'ASD(123)'; => '123'
'ASD(aa(10)asda(459))'; => 'aa(10)asda(459)'
```

So first there is some text (always text). Then there is a (, and it always ends with a ). I want the value between.

Comment: You escaped the wrong closing `)`, so your capturing group ends and then you match the `)` (when it should be the other way around). Voting off-topic because the problem is a typographic error.

Comment: Unless there are specific restrictions on the input, this is pretty tough to solve with a regex. Depending on what is allowable in the input and what isn't, only an actual parser may be able to do this properly.

Comment: what should be matched in this case `'some text (num(10a ) ss) STR("ABC(t)")'` ?

Comment: `/("\w+\(.*?\)")/` should work in this case.

Comment: @Quentin No, the escape is correct. The problem is the input is ambiguous, wrt. what the regex matches and what OP *wants* to match.

Comment: If the string is not part of a longer string, `/\((.+)\)/` will do. More details about the input are necessary.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I think the specification is quite clear that you would return `num(10a ) ss) STR("ABC(t)"` "Text then open paren, it ends with a paren - the text in between.  It might not make logical sense, but that is a solid spec.

Comment: Regular Expressions are not the right tool, if you have to *parse* text (i.e. *counting opening brackets*).

Comment: It is so simple, just use this regex `\(.*\)`

Comment: Nowhere does it say that this is supposed to parse text to match parens.   That seems to be the assumption in many comments, but it doesn't say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use greedy dot matching inside Group 1 pattern: `/\((.+)\)/`. It will match the first `(`, then any 1+ chars other than linebreak symbols and then the last `)` in the line.

```js
var vals = ['STR("ABC(t)")', 'ASD("123")', 'ASD(123)', 'ASD(aa(10)asda(459))'];
var regExp = /\((.+)\)/;
for (var val of vals) {
  var matches = regExp.exec(val);
  console.log(val, "=>", matches[1]);
}
```

**Answering the comment**: If the texts to extract must be inside nested balanced parentheses, either a small parsing code, or [`XRegExp#matchRecursive`](http://xregexp.com/api/#matchRecursive) can help. Since there are lots of parsing codes around on SO, I will provide `XRegExp` example:

```js
var str = 'some text (num(10a ) ss) STR("ABC(t)")';
var res = XRegExp.matchRecursive(str, '\\(', '\\)', 'g');
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should include `some text (num(10a ) ss) STR("ABC(t)")` in the test data set ;) :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade: No, OP has no such texts. Anyway, I can add a solution for this string, too. Need it?

Comment: I was just joking about the question in comments.   The question in comments is designed to illustrate whether or not the regex is intended to parse matching parens, which I believe it is not.